# ORA-29278: error transitorio de SMTP: 451 5.7.3 STARTTLS is required to send

Tags: oracle, email, plsql

**Hi, I'm startating to use PLSQL, I tried to send a simple email just for a test in PLSQL using UTL_MAIL, it's the first time I use UTL_MAIL, this is my code:**

```
@?/rdbms/admin/utlmail.sql
@?/rdbms/admin/prvtmail.plb

ALTER SYSTEM SET SMTP_OUT_SERVER="smtp.live.com";


    BEGIN
  UTL_MAIL.send(sender => 'example@hotmail.com',
            recipients => 'test1@hotmail.com',
               subject => 'Test Mail',
               message => 'Hello World',
             mime_type => 'text; charset=us-ascii');
END;
/
```

I tried with smtp_out_server SMTP.LIVE.COM and SMTP.OFFICE365.COM

**And this is the error:**

```
ERROR line 1:
ORA-29278: transient SMTP error: 451 5.7.3 STARTTLS is required to send
mail [SA0PR11CA0172.namprd11.prod.outlook.com]
ORA-06512: en "SYS.UTL_MAIL", lÝnea 662
ORA-06512: en "SYS.UTL_SMTP", lÝnea 57
ORA-06512: en "SYS.UTL_SMTP", lÝnea 140
ORA-06512: en "SYS.UTL_SMTP", lÝnea 476
ORA-06512: en "SYS.UTL_MAIL", lÝnea 444
ORA-06512: en "SYS.UTL_MAIL", lÝnea 679
ORA-06512: en lÝnea 3
```

I followed these instructions, but the result was the same.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13835_01/doc/doc.102/b25166/cfrulset.htm
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Send_mail_from_PL/SQL#Send_mail_with_UTL_SMTP

Please, I need help :(

Comment: It is unlikely that you'll be able to use either of those SMTP servers with `utl_smtp` or `utl_mail`.  They will almost certainly require at least authentication if not more in order to be willing to relay mail from an unknown host.  If you want to use those packages, you'd want to connect to an internal SMTP server.  You may be able to use `utl_tcp` to send email with one of those servers but you'd need documentation from Microsoft on exactly what their SMTP servers require.

Comment: Microsoft requires encryption, so you need to send a [STARTTLS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_SMTP.html#GUID-3692D4DA-357E-48F7-88CD-6D905EA1F663) command to start. You will also need to set up an Oracle wallet to do SSL/TLS.

Comment: Few examples: 1) https://rychly.gitlab.io/post/oracle-utl-smtp-via-tls/  2) https://mikepargeter.wordpress.com/2012/11/06/utl_smtp-starttls/